# How to determine what kind of data is stored in NSUserDefaults

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsuserdefaults

I am currently storing an `NSUInteger` in `NSUserDefaults` to persist data, but I need to move over to an `NSObject` that is `NSCoding` compliant and that will be stored as `NSData`. Is there a way to determine whether I am storing an int or an object in my key so that I can accommodate users who have or have not migrated from one persistence type to the other? I know `objectForKey` returns an id, so is this good enough?

```
- (id) returnStuff {
NSData *data = [myUserDefaults objectForKey:myKey];
if([data isKindOfClass:[NSData class]) {
    // then it must be an archived object
    return (desiredObjectClass*)[NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithData:data];
}
else { 
    NSUInteger returnInt = [myUserDefaults integerForKey:myKey];
    return [NSNumber numberWithInteger: returnInt];
}
```

Comment: if you've already written the code, why don't you test the code and find out?

Comment: @HaydenHolligan because in some situations that can be a lot of work and/or there's no going back, so I was hoping for at least preliminary warning or confirmation that this is ok int theory.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `isKindOfClass:` to treat `NSData` specially, as you have done, except I wouldn't bother unboxing the integer only to rebox it.  The following method handles and returns any type.

Note: there is no need to cast the unarchived data, as the compiler won't care as you are returning `id`.

```
- (id)stuffForKey:(NSString *)key {
    id value = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:key];
    if ([value isKindOfClass:[NSData class]]) {
        // then it must be an archived object
        NSData *dataValue = (NSData *)value;
        return [NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithData:dataValue];
    }
    return value;
}
```

Comment: Thanks  a lot for this helpful answer.

Comment: @helloB You're welcome.  In fact this method could be a class method as it doesn't use any instance variables.  You could stick it in your `Utils` class, perhaps...